# Reset PulseAudio (Application) Sliders on reboot?

Tags: pulseaudio, audio-volume

Using PulseAudio is awesome as long as everything works as expected, but it can also be a huge pain in the neck.

Recently, I found myself glancing at `pavucontrol` more often than I'd like to, because PA seems to remember every change I made.

For example, I occasionally use `pavucontrol` whenever I run a game and maybe TeamSpeak at the same time, so I get to hear everything as I want. I think, that's about the average scenario where PA is awesome.
What bothers me: If I don't reset the game output volume (or whatever I wanted to shut up for maybe just a moment) to 100%, it just stays, even through reboots. So next time I fire up the game it caps at maybe 50% volume and I might end up in extensive research what went wrong ... just to find out the PA-slider was still down (which requires me to start `pavucontrol`). And sometimes I see sliders in weird positions, of streams which I can't even remember to have touched ...

So I want PulseAudio to forget the Application/Stream specific settings and reset every slider to 100% at reboot.
There has to be either a setting, or this could be achieved by a script. Not sure where to begin.

Comment: Yeah, this is driving me crazy as well...

Answer (score 5):

The PulseAudio module responsible for this is [module-stream-restore](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index28h3).

The database of those streams is kept in a database file containing the string `stream-volumes` within the `~/.config/pulse/` (or `~/.pulse/` on older systems)  directory, so removing it will reset this database as suggested in the [DefaultDevice documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/DefaultDevice/).

```
rm ~/.config/pulse/*stream-volumes*
```

That page also suggests that a more systemic solution is to modify the behavior of the module by editing the loading line in `/etc/pulseaudio/default.pa`

```
load-module module-stream-restore restore_volume=false
```

This would affect the whole system, to do it only for a specific user, this could be put into `~/.config/pulse/default.pa`. Note that the **default.pa(5)** man page suggests that the file in `/etc/` won't be read in that case. Also note that this solution is not tied to rebooting, but stream existence.